# What should I do if the dialog appears only when the main activity is first executed in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to set the `bottomsheetDialog` that I made to appear only once when entering the main screen for the first time.
Currently, a dialog is created in the `onStart` function, but if you do this, the dialog appears even when you switch to the main activity from another activity.
Check my below code:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val notifyBottomDialogFragment: BottomNotifyFragment = BottomNotifyFragment {
        when (it)
        {

        }
    }
    notifyBottomDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, notifyBottomDialogFragment.tag)
    notifyBottomDialogFragment.isCancelable = false
}
```

Comment: Consider saving the fact that the sheet is displayed, may be shared preferences, or some file. Then on the next onStart, see if it was displayed before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to show a dialog in the `OnCreate` function. And save bool value to check if Activity is created the first time or not the first time (e.g. user rotate phone or go to split-screen mode):

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    companion object
    {
        var firstRun = true
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("MyTag", "Create")

        if (firstRun)
        {
            Log.d("MyTag", "Main screen showed for the first time")

            firstRun = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("MyTag", "Main screen NOT showed for the first time")
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean value within the SharedPreferences like so :

```
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("hasShownDialog", true).apply();
```

Then within your onStart or onCreate you can check preferences as so:

```
    val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
    // you have to have a default value here
    hasShownDialog = prefs.getBoolean("hasShownDialog",false)
    if(!hasShownDialog){
        showDialog()
    }
```